# Spark with Mongodb is very slow

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the spark-shell with mongodb connector. But the program was very slow , i think i will don't have the response from program.

My spark-shell command is :

```
./spark-shell --master spark://spark_host:7077 \
--conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://mongod_user:password@mongod_host:27017/database.collection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
--jars /mongodb/lib/mongo-spark-connector_2.10-2.0.0.jar,/mongodb/lib/bson-3.2.2.jar,/mongodb/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
```

And my app code is :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.mongodb.spark._
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val df = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession)
val dataset = df.filter("thisRequestTime > 1499250131596")
dataset.first // will wait to long time
```

What thing i was missed ? Help me please ~
PS: my spark is standalone model . App dependency is :

```
<properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
        <spark.version>2.1.1</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: How big is your expected dataset? How long does the query run on MongoDB?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Rick Moritz .The number of total doc is 194920414 in mongodb.  The number of doc satisfying the filter condition is 749216. I get the response after half hour in spark application. But in mongodb shell, i get the response with the same condition in millisecond.

Comment: PS : I have a index on condition field of the doc in mongodb

Comment: I have a problem just like this, any progress? almost every operation in my spark setup does not run in parallel. Save does, but not load.

Comment: @lockwobr the mongo-spak-connector will fetch the all data from mongodb , although i just want to get the first one or 'count' only, so it will be slow when the data set is big . Also, in my case, my mongodb cluster is a duplicate only and do not have the sharding . ok , if you have some other knowledge about this subject ,review to me. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I've been trapped into this kind of problem for a while, but got it over at last.
I don't know the detail of your Mongodb configuration, **but here is my solution for my problem**, hope you find it helpful.

My dataset is huge, too. So I configured a sharded cluster for mongodb, that's why make it slow. To solve it, add one piece of conf `spark.mongodb.input.partitioner=MongoShardedPartitioner`. Otherwise a default partition policy with be put into use, which is not suitable for a sharded mongodb.

You can find more specific information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration/)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@AssKicker is correct, we need use [ShardedPartitioner](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/master/configuration/read/#std-label-conf-shardedpartitioner)
Otherwise, the df.count will also report incorrect number

```
spark.read.format("mongodb")
            .option("partitioner", "com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.ShardedPartitioner")
```